# how to patch a node_module file in react native

Tags: react-native

I trying to upgrade to react native 0.70, but I'm getting some issues with some libraries,
so I need to modify some source codes.
for example:
In this file `node_modules/react-native-webengage/react-native-webengage.podspec`
changing

```
  s.source_files   = 'ios/*.{h,m}'

  s.dependency 'WebEngage'
  s.dependency 'React-Core'
end
```

to

```
  s.source_files   = 'ios/*.{h,m}'

  s.dependency 'WebEngage/XCFramework'
  s.dependency 'React-Core'
end
```

what is the best approach to do it without replacing the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patch package works perfectly with React Native https://github.com/ds300/patch-package

0. Follow instructions for patch-package from site above
1. Change the files you need (even from the native side)
2. Run `yarn patch-package react-native-webengage`
3. Add a patch to your git